# Why my script doesn't print the found password? instead, it just keeps trying other passwords

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading, zip

I'm trying to code a zip password cracker in Python 3, I want the program to print "Found password: password" when it finds the password. My problem here is that it doesn't print "found password: password" when it hits the right password, it just keeps trying other words on the list "Trying Password: password"

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile
import zipfile
import threading
import sys

filename = input("Enter File to crack: ")
wordlist = input("Enter wordlist: ")

def crackzip(filename, password):
    try:
        zipname.extractall(pwd=password)
        print ('Found password: {}'.format(password.encode('utf-8')))
        sys.exit(0)
    except:
        print ("Trying Password: {}".format(password))

def principio():
    try:
        zipname = zipfile.ZipFile(filename)
    except zipfile.BadZipfile:
        print ("File doesn't exist!")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print ("No such file or directory")

    try:
        with open(wordlist, 'r') as f:
            passlist = f.readlines()
    except IOError:
        print ("File NOT found!")

    for passwords in passlist:
        password = passwords.strip(b'\n')
        t = threading.Thread(target=crackzip, args=(filename, password))
        t.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    principio()
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `zipname` declared inside the `crackzip` function?

The try statement is always evaluating to an error like this.

```
import threading
import sys

filename = input("Enter File to crack: ")
wordlist = input("Enter wordlist: ")

def crackzip(zipname, password):
    try:
        zipname.extractall(pwd=password)
        print ('Found password: {}'.format(password.encode('utf-8')))
        sys.exit(0)
    except:
        print ("Trying Password: {}".format(password))

def principio():
    try:
        zipname = zipfile.ZipFile(filename)
    except zipfile.BadZipfile:
        print ("File doesn't exist!")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print ("No such file or directory")

    passlist = []

    try:
        with open(wordlist, 'r') as f:
            passlist = f.readlines()
    except IOError:
        print ("File NOT found!")

    for passwords in passlist:
        password = passwords.strip(b'\n')
        t = threading.Thread(target=crackzip, args=(zipname, password))
        t.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    principio()
```

Comment: same results :\